# How can I fill an array from 1 to x in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I currently have this code:

```
ans = Array.new(3)
      ans.length.times do |x|
        ans[x] = x + 1
      end
```

Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
ans = (1..3).to_a
```

This uses what Ruby calls a [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html).

Depending on what you want to do with `ans`, you may want to use the range directly without converting it to an array.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be:

```
ans = (1..3).to_a
```

Answer (score 2):

Use range and convert it into an array:

```
(1..3).to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsplat a range, like this:

```
ans = *1..3
```